# autocomplete location angularjs not work on popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

> In my application, I use google location autocomplete to suggest location when I enter some text. without popup then location autocomplete work fine but when I use location autocomplete on a popup then it not working.
>   I use a directive

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
.module('crmApp')
.directive('googleplace', directiveFunction);
directiveFunction.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

function directiveFunction($rootScope) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            details: '=?'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var options = {
                types : ['geocode']
            };
            scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);

            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                  model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('place_changed', scope.details);
              });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

})();

> then I open popup but not working:

```
<input next-on-enter type="text"  googleplace ng-model="vm.origin" class="form-control" placeholder="Vui lòng nhập xuất xứ"  maxlength="255" name="origin"/>
```

> Screen: 
>   [image: google location autocomplete]
>
> Help me, please !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> googleplace directive you write missing something to work. You need modify directive same as example in link: http://plnkr.co/edit/irQiP6waYf5kE6B4NCBe?p=preview

The input that apply autocomplete change to:

```
<input next-on-enter type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model="vm.origin" options="autoCompleteOptions" details="autoCompleteDetails" class="form-control" placeholder="Vui lòng nhập xuất xứ"  maxlength="255" name="origin"/>
```

( origin post: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/693 )

Answer (score 2):

edit your link function same as

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var options = {
                types : ['geocode']
            };

            if(scope.gPlace === undefined) {
                scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
            }

            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
                var result = scope.gPlace.getPlace();

                if(result !== undefined) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.details = result;
                        model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('place_changed', scope.details);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

hope this useful for you <3

Answer (score 0):

this code not work

```
google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
              model.$setViewValue(element.val());
              $rootScope.$broadcast('place_changed', scope.details);
          });
        });
```

because you can not use function `google.maps.event.addListener` on popup